# Trouble with Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

Hello i am using dagger 2 in my project with this configuration.

This is my SellerHubApplication.kt

```
class SellerHubApplication : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: AndroidInjector<Any>

override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = activityDispatchingAndroidInjector

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .application(this)
        .build()
        .inject(this)

    Fresco.initialize(applicationContext)
}
```

}

and this is my AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class, AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: SellerHubApplication)

}
```

After i run the application, i get this error "error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] dagger.android.AndroidInjector cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method."

if i change the "fun inject(app: SellerHubApplication)" to "fun inject(app: Application)", application runs but it says "activityDispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized". Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do it as such:

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class, AppModule::class, FragmentBuilder::class,])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector< SellerHubApplication > {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: SellerHubApplication): Builder

        fun applicationModule(applicationModule: AppModule): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Application:

```
class SellerHubApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>


    companion object {
        lateinit var applicationComponent: AppComponent
            private set
    }


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        init()
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return fragmentInjector
    }


    private fun init() {
        initDagger()
    }

    private fun initDagger() {
        applicationComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .applicationModule(AppModule(this))
                .build()

        applicationComponent.inject(this)
    }

}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val application: SellerHubApplication) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application {
        return application
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using latest version of dagger. It doesn't have HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector. I will lower down the dagger version and try it. Do you have any other solution for this ?

Comment: Just replace them with HasAndroidInjector, and change the variables accordingly.

Comment: i got it. i implemented AppComponent with AndroidInjector<SellerHubApplication> and AndroidInjector<Any> as DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any> in SellerHubApplication. I finally got it. Thanks for your help.